# « Bien le bonjour » pour « Good day » au du début d'une lettre ?

Tags: salutations, correspondance, formulation

Peut-on utiliser "Bien le bonjour" pour une traduction de "Good day" au du début d'une lettre ? Par exemple:

> Good day, Jean. Did you enjoy your trip yesterday?

J'ai utilisé plusieurs fois "Bonjour" pour "Hello" alors j'aurais voulu trouver quelque chose d'autre mais qui reste assez formel. J'ai pensé utiliser "Bonne journée" mais je le trouve étrange dans ce contexte-là.

Comment: Il me semble que *good day* est informel et plutôt australien, non ?

Answer (score 2):

Je ne vois pas de problème à utiliser "*Bien le bonjour*", c'est amical et ça change du simple *bonjour*.

En revanche comme tu l'as dit, *Bonne journée* ne convient pas, c'est une formule qu'on emploie exclusivement quand on quitte la compagnie de quelqu'un (ou au sens figuré à la fin d'une lettre par exemple).

Comment: Comme vous le dites, c'est plutôt amical, et donc pas très formel.

Answer (score 1):

"Bien le bonjour" me donne une impression assez rurale. J'ai du mal à visualiser un avocat disant à Paris "Bien le bonjour" à un médecin.

Answer (score 0):

C'est une formule que les gens emploient  dans la langue parlée, on ne doit pas la trouver beaucoup dans les lettres ; elle convient à un début d'entrevue ou de rencontre mais aussi à une terminaison, c'est à dire qu'elle signifie aussi "good bye" (au revoir) en plus de "[hello](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/bien_le_bonjour)" ; elle sera cependant plus rarement utilisée pour (au revoir). Ceci dit c'est une formule comme une autre et puisque l'on utilise "bonjour" en début de lettre dans un registre familier, pourquoi ne pas utiliser "bien le bonjour" ? Même si personne n'a encore pensé à le faire il n'existe aucune raison pour se l'interdire.

"Bonjour" s'emploie dans la correspondance, les télécommunications et les médias ([Wikipédia](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bonjour)), donc il doit en aller de même pour "bien le bonjour".

Answer (score 0):

En alternative à "Hello", j'utiliserais:

Pour le matin (en arrivant au travail):

> Bonjour!
>   Salut!
>   Salutations!
>   Et bonjour!

Pour le soir (en quittant le travail):

> Bonsoir!
>   Bonne soirée!
>   À demain!

À propos de "Bonne journée", cette expression est utilisée principalement en fin de matinée et en début d'après-midi.

Answer (score 0):

Bien le bonjour à vous,

J'utilise personnellement cette façon de saluer à l'occasion, autant à l'oral qu'à l'écrit. Je ne dirais pas que c'est la norme par contre. Je suis dans la région Montréalaise au Québec et j'en connais peu qui utilisent cette salutation.

Un peu comme Mathieu Bouville disait, ça sonne rurale un peu mais j'irais plus dire que c'est le genre de parlé que l'on utilisait auparavant. Et comme disait Teleporting Goat, je trouve que c'est sympathique et original, en général ça fait sourire les gens, c'est un bon moyen de commencer une conversation ;)

Sinon, effectivement, le "Bonne journée" s'utilise plus en fin de lettre qu'au début.

En espérant que ça va aider un peu :)

Passez une bien belle journée,

Alex.